# Linking variables

Tags: javascript, node.js

This a simple summary of my code:

```
var list = {
    "group":{
        "subgroup1":[{"name1":"Jimmy","name2":"Bob"}],
        "subgroup2":[{"name1":"Sarah","name2":"Nick"},{"name1":"Kevin","name2":"George"}]
    }
}
function group(group,name){
    var linktothegroup;

    //Note: In my actual code it will attempt to join a group before creating one this just creates a new one


    //group: Specifies which subgroup to join (my actual code will check if it's valid this is just a simpler version
    //name: the users name

    list["group"][group].push({"name1":name,"name2":""});
    linktothegroup = someway to link that group I just added; //I figured I could find the array slot and specify but that will change if a group is deleted

    this.leavegroup = function(){
        //leaves the group
        //uses the linktothegroup var to be removed from the group
    }
    this.changename = function(name){
        linktothegroup.name1 = name;
        return true;
    }
}
var cubscouts = new group("subgroup1","Billy");
cubscouts.changename("Fred");
```

I just wanna be able to edit values in the "subgroupX" fields (Basically for the changename function), but there are groups leaving and joining all the time so I can't specify the array slot in a variable.

So basically is there a way to edit one variable and have another variable change with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this?:

```
var groups = {

  joinGroup: function(groupName, memberName) {
    if(!this[groupName]) {  // create the group if it doesn't exist
      this[groupName] = []  // each group is just an array of names
    }
    var group = this[groupName]
    group.push(memberName)

    // returns an object allowing for the member's name to be changed later
    return {
      // this function becomes a closure, so the group and memberName variables
      // retain their values from the enclosing scope
      changeName: function(newMemberName) {
        group.splice(group.indexOf(memberName), 1, newMemberName)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which allows for this usage:

```
myCubscoutMembership = groups.joinGroup('cubscouts', 'Billy')
myCubscoutMembership.changeName('Bob')
```

The key piece of the puzzle (if i understand your question correctly) is that the `changeName` function is returned as a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) around the `group` and `memberName` variables - so even when `changeName` is called at a later time, the correct group and old name are remembered.

To keep the answer focused I've left out the `leaveGroup()` method but that can be added to the returned object as another function.  I'm also not addressing what would happen if a whole group is removed but that depends on what makes sense for your app.

A couple of simplifications from your original sample:

1. I flattened the top-level `list` var which seemed to contain only one `group`.
2. I simplified each group to be an array of names instead of a hash, i.e. 
   `['billy', 'bob']` instead of `{ name1: 'billy', name2: 'bob' }`.

Hope some of this helps.

Comment: Brilliant. I see no issues with it and hopefully it'll work! I'll check it off once I set mine up and see if I find any issues.

Comment: No worries. Let me know if any of your tweaks should be incorporated into the answer (or feel free to edit it as you see fit).

Comment: Yes there is one very important one, (only applies to Node.js) you made a variable called group and all the functions use that, the issue with that is it keeps the original values of the group when you call that function, so if someone joins the group as well and then you go to change your name or leave, you won't be working with their input. (basically "group" is caching the group value)

Answer (score 1):

You can store the object in a variable that you reference in the functions.

```
function group(group,name){
    //other work here
    var linktothegroup = {"name1":name,"name2":""};
    list["group"][group].push(linktothegroup);

    this.leavegroup = function(){
        var groups = list["group"][group];
        for(var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
            if(groups[i] === linktothegroup) {
                groups.splice(i, 1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    this.changename = function(name){
        linktothegroup.name1 = name;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: First off thanks for taking the time to make this code, I appreciate it but unfortunately this won't work for me. The reason I have that variable outside the function is because it will be edited by more than one person at a time. I'm using this in Node.js and this will be used like a group system, so if I did that and pushed it after I was done in the function then the people in my group wouldn't see it. Now I thought of overwriting it but that would be defeating the purpose because I would have the find the slot number again and I might as well just edit the value if I can find it.

Comment: @GarrettR linktothegroup won't be overwritten each time you call 'new group()' Each call will create a new variable that will be available inside of that group's functions.

Comment: I ment that the "subgroupX" object will be overwritten.

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to overwrite list["group"][group] each time new group() is called?

Comment: Let me rephrase it. That list variable is constantly being edited and viewed by multiple users and I want to be able to change my name in the group after I have joined/created a group, and if I was to do it your way then I would be overwriting the group I was in and removing others from that group.